# Rspec: sign_in using capybara doesn't work in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm working on exercise 9 from chapter 9 in Rails Tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#fnref-9_9 
"Modify the destroy action to prevent admin users from destroying themselves. (Write a test first.)"

I started with creating test:
users_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  describe "admins-userscontroller" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    it "should not be able to delete themself" do
      sign_in admin
      expect { delete :destroy, :id => admin.id }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end
end
```

however, noticed that even if logic for prohibiting admin to delete himself is not implemented, test passes unless I change line

```
sign_in admin
```

to

```
sign_in admin, no_copybara: true
```

after this change test fails (as expected)

sign_in is in support\utilities.rb file and looks like this:

```
def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work with capybara? It looks like the "else" section of the above code fails/doesn't execute when using capybara but it doesn't return any error (e.g. that "Email" field is not found, so it looks like it's rendered)...

Other problem is that if I remove non_admin instead of admin:

```
expect { delete :destroy, :id => non_admin.id }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

test passes which means non_admin isn't deleted... why does it work for admin and not non_admin?

Question 2:
capybara is not supposed to work in request spec as of 2.0+, but Im using capybara 2.1 and rspec-rails 2.13.1 and it works just fine in request specs (actually that's even what tutorial tells us to do), doesn't even output any warning...

Comment: Are you using `devise`?

Comment: youre confused between controller and feature specs, controller spec do not use a browser

Comment: The reason @backpackerhh is asking if you're using Devise is because it seems like you're using Devise.  From Devise' documentation: If you're wondering why we can't just use Devise's built in sign_in and sign_out methods, it's because these require direct access to the request object which is not available while using Capybara. To bundle the functionality of both methods together you can create a helper method.

Comment: @apneadiving I know conceptionally using capybara in the controller spec is not quite right, but shouldn't it technically work? Or at least return some error? If I run it with capybara test passes (although it shouldn't), if I add ,no_capybara: true, test fails (as expected)... I just found it weird.

Comment: I tested it and capybara works in controller specs (even though it's not recommended), so why doesn't sign_in method work when using capybara in the example above? Any ideas?